# java.lang.ClassCastException Error while fetching server resource using Restlet framework

Tags: java, restlet, eclipse-emf

I am trying to build a sample REST server using Restlet framework. I have downloaded the restlet framework from https://restlet.com/open-source/downloads/current/ and unzipped in D:/restlet-jse-2.3.12 Windows folder.
Now, I created an Eclipse Maven Project without archetype and added the restlet jars by project->right click->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External Jars. 
I have committed my code at https://github.com/imaynotbereal/curly-sniffle/tree/master/restlet1

While building my code I got multiple NoClassDefFoundError errors like below:

```
    Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.jdbc.JdbcClientHelper

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:896)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:928)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:968)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConnectors(Engine.java:654)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:491)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:382)
```

I realized that there were sub-folders under D:/restlet-jse-2.3.12/lib and I had to add the jars inside them into the Java Build Path->Libraries(jars under D:/restlet-jse-2.3.12/lib/org.apache.commons.dbcp_1.3 folder for the above error)

Now the build is fine, all NoClassDefFoundError errors had been resolved and the server starts to listen on port 8081. However, when I request for a resource using below the URL http://localhost:8081/product, I get a ClassCastException error:

```
Exception or error caught in server resource

java.lang.ClassCastException: Product cannot be cast to org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
    at org.restlet.ext.emf.EmfConverter.toRepresentation(EmfConverter.java:211)
    at org.restlet.service.ConverterService.toRepresentation(ConverterService.java:342)
    at org.restlet.resource.Resource.toRepresentation(Resource.java:945)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:515)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.get(ServerResource.java:723)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:603)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doNegotiatedHandle(ServerResource.java:662)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doConditionalHandle(ServerResource.java:348)
    at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.handle(ServerResource.java:1020)
    at org.restlet.resource.Finder.handle(Finder.java:236)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:641)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:140)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:202)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:77)
    at org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:385)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:641)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)
    at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:641)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:140)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)
    at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)
    at org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:202)
    at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:408)
    at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:507)
    at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:63)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:143)
    at org.restlet.ext.jetty.JettyServerHelper$WrappedServer.handle(JettyServerHelper.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2019-01-04  17:14:43    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -   0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 8081    GET /product    -   500 486 0   84  http://localhost:8081   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36  -
```

I checked my Referenced Libraries, the jars under D:/restlet-jse-2.3.12/liborg.eclipse.emf_2.6 folder are included so it seems unlikely that the above error is due to missing jars.

I checked the examples in Restlet documentation, but can't understand where the problem lies.

I know manually trying to add each dependent jar to the Build References is bad, but I do not know of a better way at the moment. I'd be happy if someone can guide me how to add jar to Java application more efficiently in this scenario.

Comment: You need to add mapping for the /product route. Subclass a ServerResource and register it for URL.

Comment: I did create a mapping in https://github.com/imaynotbereal/curly-sniffle/blob/master/restlet1/src/main/java/Myapplication.java

ProductResource  is a subclass of ServerResource

Comment: Ok, thanks. How would you then like to marshall the Product into HTTP response? I think you need to tell the framework that.